# When do you specify the Target variable in a SageMaker Training job?

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to create a Machine Learning algorithm following this tutorial : [Get Started with Amazon SageMaker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-console.html)

Unless I missed something in the tutorial, I didn't find any steps where we specify the target variable. Can someone explain where / when we specify our target variable when creating an ML model using SageMaker built-in algorithms?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I agree, completely non-intuitive. It shouldn't be a "Note" at the bottom of the tutorial in the [link to SageMaker XGBoost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html#InputOutput-XGBoost) that Olivier posted below.
* `For CSV training, the algorithm assumes that the target variable is in the first column and that the CSV does not have a header record.`
* `For CSV inference, the algorithm assumes that CSV input does not have the label column.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the scientific paradigm you're using in SageMaker :)

- SageMaker Built-in algorithms all have their input specification,
  described in their respective documentation. For example, for
  [SageMaker Linear Learner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/linear-learner.html#ll-input_output) and [SageMaker XGBoost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html#InputOutput-XGBoost) the target is assumed
  to be the first column.
- With custom code, such as Bring-Your-Own-Docker or SageMaker Framework containers (for Sklearn, TF, PyTorch, MXNet) since you are the one writing the code you can write any sort of logic, and the target can be any column of your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of research, I found the answer. If you are using a CSV file pulled from an S3 bucket, the target variable is assumed to be on the first column.

If you need more details, you can check out this part of AWS documentation:

[Common Data Format For Training](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-training.html)